# How to run an ordered test

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I want to

- fill out name and password input fields
- click login button
- wait for page to load
- click a button

How can I accomplish this?  I realize promises are going to be involved.  This is what I have tried:

### conf.js

```
var env = require('./environment.js');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['test/e2e/app/test-spec.js'],

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,

  onPrepare: function() {
    console.log("base url is: " + env.baseUrl);
    browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '#/login');

    element(by.model('my.username')).sendKeys('username');
    element(by.model('my.password')).sendKeys('password');

    console.log("clicking login button...");
    element(by.css('button.md-primary.md-button.md-default-theme')).click();

    // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
    // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
    // /#/home.html.
    browser.driver.wait(function() {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        console.log("read current url as" + url);
        console.log("returning...");

        return  /\/#\/home\//.test(url);
      });
    }, 10000);
  }
};
```

Then a test.

### test-spec.js

```
describe('Click button on home page', function() {
  it('should click the button', function() {
    console.log("looking for button on home page")
    element(by.css('button.md-fab.md-accent.md-primary.md-button.md-default-theme')).click();
  });
});
```

And for reference

### environment.js

```
// Common configuration files with defaults plus overrides from environment vars
var webServerDefaultPort = 9002;

module.exports = {
 // The address of a running selenium server.
 seleniumAddress:
   (process.env.SELENIUM_URL || 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub'),

 // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
 capabilities: {
   'browserName':
       (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_NAME || 'chrome'),
   'version':
       (process.env.TEST_BROWSER_VERSION || 'ANY')
 },

 // Default http port to host the web server
 webServerDefaultPort: webServerDefaultPort,

 // A base URL for your application under test.
 baseUrl:
   'http://' + (process.env.HTTP_HOST || 'localhost') +
         ':' + (process.env.HTTP_PORT || webServerDefaultPort)

};
```

#### Outputs

> Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
>   [launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
>   base url is: http://localhost:9002
>   clicking login button...
>   looking for button on home page

I never see `"read current url as"` which tells me the promise is not executing and my test executes too early.

So the Error I get makes sense because the test ran too early:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: By.cssSelector("button.md-> fab.md-accent.md-primary.md-button.md-default-theme")

Answer (score 1):

Put the `wait()` call into `beforeEach()`:

```
describe('Click button on home page', function() {

  beforeEach(function () {
    browser.wait(function() {
      return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
        console.log("read current url as" + url);
        console.log("returning...");

        return  /\/#\/home\//.test(url);
      });
    }, 10000);
  });

  it('should click the button', function() {
    console.log("looking for button on home page")
    element(by.css('button.md-fab.md-accent.md-primary.md-button.md-default-theme')).click();
  });
});
```

---

Or, you can wait for the element on the home page to become visible:

```
describe('Click button on home page', function() {
  var scope = {};

  beforeEach(function () {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    scope.defaultTheme = element(by.css('button.md-fab.md-accent.md-primary.md-button.md-default-theme'));
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(scope.defaultTheme), 10000);
  });

  it('should click the button', function() {
    console.log("looking for button on home page");
    scope.defaultTheme.click();
  });
});
```

Comment: What does `onPrepare:` look like in the first case?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey yeah, try removing the wait in onPrepare and use it in beforeEach.

Answer (score 1):

After tinkering around I had the most success with the following setup:

- `beforeAll()` used to login

  - `sendkeys()` failed to function for me inside of `OnPrepare()`.  I shortened `OnPrepare()` down to a simple redirect to login page.
- I set config.js to use firefox because I had problems getting `click()` to function in chrome.
- Use Jasmine2 (jasmine1 is default)
- Use a series of `browser.wait` to workout the timing.  You can wait for an element to exist (one that only exists on page2 per-se)

  - `browser.waitForAngular()` performs similar duties.  I had less success with this feature
- [Protractor configuration file documentation](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js)

### test-spec.js

```
    describe('Click button on home page', function() {
      beforeAll(function () {
        element(by.model('my.username')).sendKeys('username');
        element(by.model('my.password')).sendKeys('password');
        element(by.id('loginButton')).click();

        browser.wait(function() {
          return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            var result = url.indexOf("/#/home") > -1;//wait for url to change to this
            return result;
          });
        }, 10000);
      });

      it('should click the button', function() {
        console.log("executing test...");   
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;//Yea I had to use this here too...I dunno why this is required

        element(by.id('someButton')).click();
        browser.wait(function() {
           console.log('inside wait for vm.firstName');
           return browser.isElementPresent(by.model('vm.firstName'));
        }, 10000).then(function(){
          //rinse and repeat with more waits as pages change
        });
        expect(true).toBe(true);
      });
    });
```

### conf.js

```
var env = require('./environment.js');

exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  specs: ['test/e2e/app/test-spec.js'],

  baseUrl: env.baseUrl,

  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox'
  },

  framework: 'jasmine2',

  onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get(env.baseUrl + '#/login');
  }
};
```

### environment.js

no change